# Setting function parameter inside then block with firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to set an object parameter inside a then block when dealing with firestore but for some reason it is not getting set. Is there something wrong with my syntax? I figured using `=>` would allow me to do this.

```
updateLedger(id: string, data: any) {
    this.afs.collection('chartofaccounts').doc(id).ref.get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.data().normalside === 'debit') {
        ///// set the runningBalance of the data object passed into the function here
        data.runningBalance = doc.data().debitAmount - doc.data().creditAmount;
      } else {
        ///// or here...
        data.runningBalance = doc.data().creditAmount - doc.data().debitAmount;
      }
    });
    return this.afs.collection('ledger').add(data);
  }
```

Comment: I suspect its because you're trying to use `data` before the asynchronous operation has completed.

Comment: @amy so how can I set the `runningBalance` attribute?

Comment: You don't have to return synchroniously but rather use a promise or a callback, becaseu you are adding data which has not yet set the runingBalance...

Comment: @V.Sambor so how would I go about doing that then?

Comment: I will write in answer a possible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible way to do it, but I'm not sure you really need a callback, the important think is just to add `this.afs.collection('ledger').add(data);` this line in the `.then` when the promise is resolve (async). I also put the callback for you to check if is helpful.

```
updateLedger(id: string, data: any, callback: function) {
  this.afs.collection('chartofaccounts').doc(id).ref.get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.data().normalside === 'debit') {
      ///// set the runningBalance of the data object passed into the function here
      data.runningBalance = doc.data().debitAmount - doc.data().creditAmount;

      // You set it here maybe you don't even need the callback
      this.afs.collection('ledger').add(data);
      callback(data);
    } else {
      ///// or here...
      data.runningBalance = doc.data().creditAmount - doc.data().debitAmount;

      // You set it here maybe you don't even need the callback
      this.afs.collection('ledger').add(data);
      callback(data);
    }
  });
}

// In the call you receive the result
updateLedger(id, data, (resultData) => {
  console.log(resultData)
})
```

Make sure the `then` is called if not, add a `.catch` statement, maybe there are some other problems ...